# How to Remove Attribute of Control from Code Behind in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to Remove Attribute background from code Behind.
This is my Xaml Code -

```
<Button Name="btnBack" Width="50" Height="50"></Button>
```

And Xml.cs

```
btnBack.Background = Brushes.Red;
```

But after some operation i want to remove this attribute with value 
so my button should come as its original color and "Red" should Remove.

Can Any one help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    // first store its original color
    Brush Originalcolor = btnBack.Background;

    // on some condition
    btnBack.Background = Brushes.Red;

    // afte some other condition
    btnBack.Background = Originalcolor;
```

Comment: Mine and @Clemens answer are to *clear* value if it wasn't set earlier in xaml. This approach (remember-set-restore) is more common and will work in both cases, though it doesn't take [nature of dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) in account, to example, if value was set by style, then in your code you set it locally, mean you breaking style triggers from being able to change value after you *restore* it like this.

Answer (score 7):

Reset the property to its default value by calling [DependencyObject.ClearValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597464.aspx):

```
btnBack.ClearValue(Control.BackgroundProperty);
```

This clears a so-called local value (e.g. any value set directly or by a Binding), but keeps any potential value set by a Style.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set value of dependency property to [`UnsetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
btnBack.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue);
```

It's not as good as [@Clemens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47220830/1997232) but it seems to work and can be used in one liner with `?:` to either set or clear value.

Comment: @Clemens, I did only very simple test. Do you mean what calling `ClearValue()` will restore binding in xaml (deleted by setting value in code)?

Comment: No I thought UnsetValue might be passed to the Binding's source property. But that won't happen. The binding is removed just as if you had called ClearValue.

Comment: @Clemens, looking in [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,da7494dcf1a1a7d5) of `SetValue` [there is a check](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/DependencyObject.cs,664) if new value is `UnsetValue` and it will call `ClearValue()`.